# UIView animation change image of button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have `UIButton` and i want to change is image with animation (change 4 images), i tried this method but it only change to the last image.

what i try to do is to put small image of the `UIButton` from the currently image.

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

## Edit

```
-(void)animationPlayButton:(NSString*)name{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"pause"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"pause1" context:NULL];
    }else if ([name isEqualToString:@"play"]){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"play1" context:NULL];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(buttonAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"pause"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PLAY_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)buttonAnimationDidStop:(NSString*)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context{
    if (!animationID) {
        NSLog(@"null");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",animationID);

    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause1"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"pause2" context:NULL];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play1"]){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"play2" context:NULL];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause2"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"pause3" context:NULL];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play2"]){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"play3" context:NULL];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause3"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play3"]){
        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(buttonAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause1"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play1"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PLAY_3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause2"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play2"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PLAY_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"pause3"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PAUSE_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"play3"]) {
        [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Control_PLAY_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the same state in each line ? (`UIControlStateNormal`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try would be to create a **custom UIButton** and 
add a UIImageView as it's view.

Then you can simply use UIImageView's animation - one
of tutorials is [here](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html).

I just tested the code below and it works. Not exactly as you want to but i'm sure you'll
manage to modify the code for your needs.

The code below adds 4 images and animates them in an endless loop.
You'll probably want to keep a reference to animationView so you can start/stop
animation whenever you want. Or if there will be more animated buttons in you app you might consider subclassing UIButton.

```
-(void) createButton {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonClicked)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 140.0);

    UIImageView *animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,160.0,140.0)];


    NSMutableArray* imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Frame_0.tiff"]];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Frame_1.tiff"]];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Frame_2.tiff"]];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Frame_3.tiff"]];

    animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    [animationView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

    [button addSubview: animationView];

    [animationView startAnimating];

    [self.viewController.view addSubview:button];
}
```